# How to call onClick() from other class

Tags: java, android, onclick

**Class-1**

```
public class MyHeader {

private Button button1,button2;

public MyHeader(Activity source) {
   this.button1 = (Button)source.findViewById(R.id.b_one);
   this.button2 = (Button)source.findViewById(R.id.b_two); 
   // ...
   }

public Button getHeaderButtonOne() { return button1; }
// And so on...
```

**class-2**

```
private MyHeader header;
 // ... in onCreate() method
  header = new MyHeader(this);
```

Using this code, in class 2 I am able to access the button for which I got the id in class1. Now I want to get the onclick event for the button set in class 1 and if i get the button in class 2 I should be able to use the click event also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new method in your **class-1**:

```
public void clickButton1(){
   button1.performClick();
}
```

and call it from your **class-2** like this:

```
header.clickButton1();
```